# What do we need to configure, to send emails with Laravel?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, smtp, swiftmailer

When using Nodemailer in Node.js, we need to have a SMTP server setup, in order to deliver the messages. For example, most commonly used SMTP servers are given [here](https://www.wpoven.com/blog/free-smtp-servers-sending-emails/).

What I wonder is, when sending emails using Laravel, do we need to setup the same SMPT server as we do for Node.js? Here is the difference that is confusing me:

- when using Node.js, I can install the package as a library and then I need to usually provide an api-key (which I can get from the SMTP server). For example (for SendInBlue) we install the library, we import the corresponding package, we specify the api key and we are ready to use it based on the specification

```
// Include the Sendinblue library\
var SibApiV3Sdk = require('sib-api-v3-sdk');
var defaultClient = SibApiV3Sdk.ApiClient.instance;
// Instantiate the client
var apiKey = defaultClient.authentications['api-key'];
apiKey.apiKey = 'YOUR_API_V3_KEY';
```

- when using Laravel, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail) I found that it works with [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) and this whole setup looks kind of different that the Node.js approach. Here, I see that domain, port and protocol are defined, but I don't see API's keys from above (plus I am not sure from where the values for domain, port and protocol are get)

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 25);
// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// or even some more advanced approaches

// Option #1: SMTPS = SMTP over TLS (always encrypted):
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 587, 'ssl');
// Option #2: SMTP with STARTTLS (best effort encryption):
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 587, 'tls');
```

**So what do we actually need when we want to use mailing with Laravel?** Do we need the same SMTP server (for example, from the list I provided above) OR Laravel works on adifferent way and we need something else to setup and to get the config values (like domain, port and protocol)?

Comment: Here you can see as an example sending mails using [SendGrid](https://usingphp.com/post/send-transactional-email-with-sendgrid-in-laravel) SMTP in Laravel

Answer (score 1):

You could also configure in the .env file of your project

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```